# Rails search with sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, full-text-search, sunspot

I have one to many association between jobs and companies and i have implemented a search form for jobs using sunspot gem but i want when i search a company_name i have all jobs results of the company searched how can i do this

this is my job model

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :company




searchable do
  text :job_title, boost: 4
  text :profile_recherche
end
```

this is my company model

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :jobs
```

this is my jobs search controller

```
def search

@jobs = Sunspot.search(Job) do
  keywords params[:query]
  fulltext params[:query]
  paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 1)
end.results

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :action => "index" }
end

end
```

Comment: At what point exactly are you searching for companies? This is only a search for jobs... Shouldn't you have searchable fields for Company model?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to search Jobs by job_title, profile_reserche, and company.name. If I'm guessing what you want correctly, changing your searchable block like so should do it:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :company

  searchable do
    text :job_title, boost: 4
    text :profile_recherche
    text :company_name do
      company.name
    end
  end
end
```

One caveat here is that if you have overlap in tokens, stems, n-grams, whatever between these various fields, you could have some interesting search results.